# Quadrupole moment of point charges?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, multipole-expansion

We know that due to expansion, the Quadrupole potential equals $$1/4\pi \epsilon r^3 . \int (r^\prime)^2(\frac32. \cos^2\theta^\prime-\frac12)\rho(r^\prime)d\tau$$

but what is the equation for point charges? for example, we have two charge $q$ and one charge $-2q$ with defined locations.

Comment: what is $\rho$?

Comment: ρ is the volumetric charge density

Comment: and how does $\rho$ look like for your example?

Comment: imagine the the 2q is at "0", one of the q charges is at "+l" and the other q is at "-l" and they're all at one line

Comment: Go [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elequad.html). What you are describing is called a linear electric quadrupole.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to understand how a **point charge** is represented in the **charge density** $\rho(r)$.

The concept you need is the **Dirac delta function** $\delta(r)$, which can describe the density of a finite amount of stuff packed into an infinitesimal point:

$$\delta(r) = \left\{ ^{\infty \text{ if } r=0 }_{0 \text{ if } r\ne0} \right\} $$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x) dx = 1$$

And it has the following really useful property:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\delta(x-a) dx = f(a)$$

And in your case the the charge density could be written

$$\rho(r') = q\delta(r'-r_1) + q\delta(r'-r_2) - 2q\delta(r'-r_3)$$

Where $r_i$ is the location of the $i$th charge. The useful property above makes it easy to calculate your integral.

Comment: Further reading on the delta function is recommended. I really like this Khan Academy video: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/laplace-transform/properties-of-laplace-transform/v/dirac-delta-function